# What would cause Finder's "Find" (cmd-F) to launch a server connection?

Tags: finder, mojave, spotlight, search

I've seen similar questions about strange server connections, but they didn't apply to this issue.

Very specifically, when I hit <kbd>Command</kbd><kbd>F</kbd>, my Mac automatically, and silently, connects to one of my servers.  I looked in "Keychain Access" to see if there was a password to remove, and there wasn't.  There's also no reference to the server in "Login Items".  If I notice it, and disconnect it, I can continue to do Finds, and it usually won't try to reconnect.  However, if I open a new window, and then do the Find, every "New Finder Window/Find" sequence will cause a reconnection.

It took me forever to isolate that Find is what's causing this connection, but I can't determine why.

(Running Mojave - 10.14.6)

Comment: Have you checked the short cuts under the keyboard settings?

Comment: What is the share?  Is it being indexed by Spotlight?  Is it in your `/etc/fstab`?

Comment: I didn't find anything in any of the keyboard settings.  It's also not in 'fstab.hd', which looks to be a deprecated file, from the "IGNORE THIS FILE" inside it.  I tried adding if to Spotlight's "Privacy" tab, but once unmounted, the item drops from the list.